# function showing warnings in mysql that data truncate for column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using function for UTC timestamp value. function(NOW(),19800);
19800 is offset value that I have calculate before. When I use tis function near insert query ->

```
insert into Table_nm values('function(NOW(),19800)');
```

Table_nm contain DateTime field.but when I insert query,It has inserted but inserting 0000-00-00 and 00:00:00 value. Shows warnings that,

> Data truncated for column 'Column_nm' at row 1`or`Out of range value for column 'Column_nm' at row 1`

I have check function separately by

`select function(NOW(),19800);`

yes, It works. But It does not work in insert syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `function(NOW(),19800)` within quotes. If you use within quotes it is treated as string. You can use it without quotes in the insert statement, like you did while checking the select statement.

Comment: Thank you. It work. But one more question how to use in php code.$sql="INSERT INTO Table_nm".
         "(Column_nm,Column_nm1) "."VALUES(function(TIMESTAMP($SDDATE,$Starttime),$SEC),function(TIMESTAMP($EDDATE,$Endtime),$SEC))";

Comment: I think it would be best if you mark this answer given above as correct. And post a new question regarding the question above given in your comments. That's the recommended practice at StackExchange. However, from your question (a bit unclear) given above in the comments, here is a possible answer to it : 

$sql = "INSERT INTO Table_nm(Column_nm,Column_nm1) " . "VALUES(function(TIMESTAMP( ". $SDDATE . "," . $Starttime . "," . $SEC . ")" . ",function(TIMESTAMP(" . $EDDAT‌​E . " ," . $Endtime . " , " . $SEC . " )) "

The idea is, SPACE DOT SPACE is the concatenation operator in PHP.

Comment: Thank you! and Yes Next Time will do.

Comment: Did the above answer work ? If yes, may I request you to mark the question as resolved by accepting the answer ?